# graphql query in json format

Tags: java, json, graphql, union

I created a test in which I get a graphql response for my logic.
Graphql query is created as json and there is a cast class problem

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
class com.pulkovo.rms.rscontrolwriter.service.graphql.type.TasksInfoQuery$AsResource cannot be cast to class 
com.pulkovo.rms.rscontrolwriter.service.graphql.type.TasksInfoQuery$AsITechnicalResource 
(com.pulkovo.rms.rscontrolwriter.service.graphql.type.TasksInfoQuery$As
Resource and com.pulkovo.rms.rscontrolwriter.service.graphql.type.TasksInfoQuery$AsITechnicalResource are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

in this part

```json
"resource": {
          "__typename": "Resource",
          "resourceType": "PaxBus",
          "resource": {
            "__typename": "Resource",
            "AsITechnicalResource": {
              "__typename": "Resource", //
              "erpName": "John Doe"
            }
          }
```

```
resource {
      resourceType
      resource{
        ... on ITechnicalResource{
          erpName
          ... on AircraftTug{
            typeOfTractor
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

`ITechnicalResource` is `union(interface)` , and `AircraftTug` is type, field __typename - is informative , it can be filled with any value

I think the problem is using the interface in json, since I used this format before and everything worked

```
resource {
      resourceType
      resource{
        ... on PaxBus{
          erpName
          }
        }
}
PaxBus - type
```

if you write a graphql object in the form of code, then everything turns out

```
with ITechnicalResource
TasksInfoQuery.Resource Resource1 = new TasksInfoQuery.Resource("Resource", ResourceType.AIRBRIDGE,
            new AsITechnicalResource1("typaname", "erpName"));

with AircraftTug
TasksInfoQuery.Resource Resource1 = new TasksInfoQuery.Resource("Resource", ResourceType.AIRBRIDGE,
            new AsAircraftTug("typaname", "erpName", "typeOftractor"));
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.